# Avoiding Memory Leak while referencing Activity from onResponse of Retrofit2 callback

Tags: android, memory-leaks, retrofit2, logout

Suppose we have a retrofit Callback as follows:

```
    Callback<T> callback = new Callback<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
                            mProgressBar.dismiss();
            if (response.code() == 401) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Invalid session, logging out",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Session.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).clear();
                this.navigateToLoginActivity();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    }
```

Suppose the retrofit request with this callback runs for a long time and if the activity starting the request has already finished by the time onResponse is invoked, then it will cause memory leak we are referring to the activity via

> this.navigateToLoginActivity()

So the question is how to get the context in onResponse? WeakReference? But this is such a common use case, i.e. to logout user, in case, the authentication fails. I want to know the best practice in this scenario for a general AsyncTask case and retrofit case as well.

Comment: In callback you can take a weak reference of the activity in constructor, and perform the work. Yes, it's like that. A better way would be to shift to RX, in that case you can just unsubscribe.

Comment: I ended us using Otto Bus to handle 401, thanks to the suggestion by @EpicPandaForce

Comment: But Otto is deprecated. From their docs This project is deprecated in favor of RxJava and RxAndroid. These projects permit the same event-driven programming model as Otto, but they’re more capable and offer better control of threading.

Comment: thanks a lot Debanjan. will move to Rx. been a long pending Wishlist :)